# Custom ViewController Transition always starts from the center

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a custom `ViewController` transition.
I'm basically trying to replicate Apple's animation when launching an app, the zoom in starts from the application's position.
I have a collection view, and when the user taps on a cell, I get the cell's point (which does work), and I'm trying to set the animation starting point to be that point.
And while I can see that I get the point the zoom in effect always starts from the center of the screen. This is what I have as the custom transition:

```
enum ZoomTransitionMode: Int {
  case present, dismiss, pop
}

class ZoomTransition: NSObject{
  var zoom = UIView()
  var originFrame = CGRect.zero

  var startingPoint: CGPoint!

  var zoomColor = UIColor.appWhite
  var animationDuration = 0.3
  var transitionMode: ZoomTransitionMode = .present

}

extension ZoomTransition: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

  func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
      return animationDuration
  }

  func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    switch transitionMode {
    case .present:
        if let presentedView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) {
            print(startingPoint)
            zoom = UIView()
            zoom.frame = CGRect(origin: startingPoint, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
            zoom.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            zoom.backgroundColor = zoomColor
            zoom.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)

            containerView.addSubview(zoom)


            presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
            presentedView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            presentedView.alpha = 0
            presentedView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

            containerView.addSubview(presentedView)

            containerView.bringSubviewToFront(presentedView)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
                self.zoom.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                presentedView.alpha = 1
            }) { (didSuccessed) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(didSuccessed)
            }
        }
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

I also tried setting the zoom's and the presentedView center as the starting point, but still, the animation starts from the center of the screen instead of the starting point.

Comment: Yes, an affine transform starts at the center. An easier way to control what happens here is to use a _snapshot view_ and animate its _frame_ from the initial rect (which in your case is some very small size) to the final rect (which is given by the context). Downloadable example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p301customAnimation4/NavCustomPushTest/Animator.swift

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what I want? I don't really understand the example here and how I should use it and add it to my application.

Comment: Well, think about it this way. The job of your custom transition animation is to animate the `presentedView` so that it ends up at the `finalFrame` supplied by the context. But _you_ are not examining the `finalFrame` at all, and you never set the initial frame of `presentedView` (except, wrongly, to the screen bounds). Thus it just starts at its `finalFrame`, and since all you animate is its transform, and since a transform animation starts at the center, it appears to grow from _its final center_, which is exactly what one would expect given your code.

Comment: Whereas, if you look at _my_ code, I put my view at the _initial_ correct frame and animate to the correct _final_ frame that the context gave me.

Comment: @matt, thank you. I was able to understand it logically with your explanation. I still kinda struggle to set this up on my project (Where does MasterViewController comes from?), I will work on that, but at least I kinda understand that now :).

Comment: Sorry, well, as I said, the examples in my repo are downloadable. You download the repo, find that particular project you're interested in, and open it. Now you can run the example and study how it works. It's good practice to move the custom animation out of the view controller so that's what the example does, but I don't always do that.

Comment: Actually, thanks to your explanation I kinda figured this out :), now the animation works better, I just have another problem, but I know where it comes from so I guess I will solve it too soon. Your explanation was awesome and helped me learn something I didn't knew, thank you for that!

Comment: By the way, I don't want to imply that what you are doing is wrong in and of itself — not at all. I do exactly the same thing in this example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p302addingPresentationController/PresentationController/ViewController2.swift But you see, in that example I _want_ to grow from the center of the screen! :)))))